# Undefined redux-react state in componet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am implementing a project where the data going to be shared in different components. So I decided to use redux-react for state management.

I used redux react async api call to get data from api. However I got undefined when the component mounted for the first time and returned actual data.

However, when I tried to implement some function on returned data, I got this error:

> "Cannot read property of undefined"

I can see the state in redux developer tools and it has data and the logs function display action correctly. I can not understand why I am getting undefined. Here is my code:

```
const initialState = {  
    candidate: {},
    companies: [], 
    offers: [], 
    moreStatehere:...
  }
```

**Reducer for the candidate**

```
export default function profileReducer(state = initialState, action) {  
    switch(action.type) {

      case FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        didInvalidate: true
      })

      case REQUEST_PROFILE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        didInvalidate: false
      })

      case RECEIVE_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state, 
        candidate: action.data
      }

      default: 
        return state;
    }
  }
```

**root reducer**

```
const rootReducer =  combineReducers({
  profiles: profileReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

**create store**

```
const composeEnhanser = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__||compose;
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()


export default function configureStore() {  
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeEnhanser(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware,
      loggerMiddleware))
  );
}
```

**index.js**

```
const store = configureStore(); 

const app = (
  <Provider store= {store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
     <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
)


ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**action creator/api call**

```
export function feachProfiles() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestProfile)
    return fetch(API_URL)
      .then(
        response => response.json(),
        error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
      )
      .then(json =>
        dispatch(receiveProfile(json))
      )
  }
}
```

componentuse

```
class CandidatesList extends Component {

    constructor (props){
        super (props)
      }

    componentWillMount() {
            this.props.feachProfiles(); 

        }

    handleClick() {
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
      }  

    render() {     
   const candidate = this.props.profiles.map(profile=>(
       <div> </div>
   )); 

        return (
            <div>
                 <ViewCandidate
                 />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      profiles: state.profiles.candidate || []
      }
    }
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            feachProfiles: bindActionCreators(feachProfiles, dispatch)
        }
    }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CandidatesList);  

action RECEIVE_PROFILE @ 
redux-logger.js:1  prev state {profiles: {…}}
redux-logger.js:1  action     {type: "RECEIVE_PROFILE", data: {…}}
redux-logger.js:1  next state {profiles: {…}}
```

Comment: `profiles: state.profiles.candidate || []` here the `state.profiles.candidate` isn't false because of initial state structure `candidate: {}`. This is an object and doesn't have `map` method

Answer (score 0):

make sure to write this just before map function

```
if (this.props.profiles.length === 0) return null;
```

this.props.profiles should have array length of greater than 0

```
  const candidate = this.props.profiles.map(profile=>(
           <div> </div>
       ));
```